# How can we access converted leads via external IDs?

Tags: rest-api, leads, lead-conversion

Part of our business process relies on checking some data against Lead objects. This process needs that data even after the Lead is converted.

We can certainly update our code/business process to look at both Accounts and Leads, but it's just some extra complexity that we would rather avoid unless necessary.

In summary, after a lead is converted, I can get the Lead data if I use the Lead ID via `/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Lead/00QS000000DdOxXMAV` and it returns (truncated/edited):

```json
{
  "attributes": {
    "type": "Lead",
    "url": "/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Lead/00QS000000DdOxXMAV"
  },
  "Id": "00QS000000DdOxXMAV",
  "CustomExternalField__c": "foobar"
}
```

But when trying to access the Lead *after it is converted* via `/services/data/v55.0/sobjects/Lead/CustomExternalField__c/foobar`, it does not work:

```json
[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
]
```

But again, reiterating that the query work just fine *prior* to converting the Lead.

Comment: Do you have the View Converted Leads permission? Did you try setting that on a profile/permission set?

Comment: In theory yes. Our admin specifically gave my user that permission in the sandbox so I can test this. But that did not seem to have an effect. I did generate a new token for making my REST call in Postman, but it did not change the outcome. I am able to view that lead via the ID, but not via the external ID.

Comment: the caller could use the REST SOQL query format rather than the `...CustomExternalField__c/foobar` approach

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Adds more complexity than we want in my opinion, but we'll see if anything else comes up. I am actually hoping that this is just us having not turn on something or that it's flat out not allowed..